# Кастомный TabLayout с разной шириной TabItem

Tags: java, android, xml, android-tablayout

Кто-нибудь может подсказать, как реализовать подобный TabLayout?

[image: (Взято с сайта по Material Design)]
[Ссылка на видео](https://storage.googleapis.com/spec-host-backup/mio-design%2Fassets%2F1SkeVD6imJA_MwjipNR-DbNh1xw4au9yy%2F02-rally-tabs.mp4), как это работает.

Обычными настройками `TabLayout` такого достичь не получается, в Fixed mode в принципе ширина всех вкладок одинакова, в Scrollable mode всё выглядит очень печально на разных устройствах. 
Буду очень признателен за помощь, или хотя бы намёк, в какую сторону копать.

Comment: Мне непонятен вопрос: вас что интересует - как сделать разметку шапок вкладок или разметку самих вкладок? На что надо обратить внимание в вашем видео/скриншоте? Вот честно - несколько раз перечитал, но ничего не понял

Comment: @Barmaley По сути, мне нужен такой же TabLayout как на видео, то есть - растянут на всю ширину экрана, текстовая подпись вкладки только у выбранной, содержимое TabItem (иконка и текст) выровнены по левому краю

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно внутри `TabItem` задекларировать кастомный лейаут, что то типа:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   <!--blah-blah сюда понавтыкать свои хотелки/-->

</RelativeLayout>
```

На него ссылку примерно так:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
        android:layout="@layout/mytab" //ссылка на кастомный лейаут
        android:text="Tab 1"
        android:icon="@drawable/myIcon" />

</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```